# How can I change the color of this 'CheckIn' Button when the ListViewItem is generated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I would like to have the color of the 'CheckIn' button appear as green depending on the value of some other data in my code but I am unable to access that button outside of its onClick method. I should be able to access it via its ID but for some reason am unable to

[image: Image of ListView]

```
<asp:ListView
                ID="lvInstructors"
                runat="server"
                itemwDataBound="lvDataBound"
                itemCommand="lvCommand"
                Visible="true">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <div class="container" id="mainContent">
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                </LayoutTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="row instructorItem" id="instructorItem">
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="sessionID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("SessionID")%>' />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hasChckedIn" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("hasCheckedIn")%>' />
                        <div class="col-2 sessionStartTimeDiv">
                            <p class="sessionStartTime"><%#Eval("SessionStartTime")%></p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-2 instructorHeadshotDiv">
                            <asp:Image class="instructorHeadshot" runat="server" src='<%#Eval("InstructorHeadshot")%>' />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-5 sessionInfoDiv">
                            <h3 class="instructorName"><%#Eval("InstructorName")%></h3>
                            <p class="sessionInfo"><%#Eval("SessionInfo")%></p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-3 checkInBtnDiv">

                            <asp:Button class="checkInBtn" ID="checkInBtn" runat="server" OnClick="CheckInBtn_Click" Text="Check-In"></asp:Button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                </ItemTemplate>

                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    No Sessions to Display.
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

How I access it in onClick():

```
protected void CheckInBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button checkInBtn = (Button)sender;
        checkInBtn.Text = "Check-Out";
        checkInBtn.BackColor = Color.Green;
        ...
    }
```

(Side Question: Why does SelectedIndex return -1 when I click that button ?)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question has been asked before - access a control inside a listview.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find Control Inside ListView Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903094/find-control-inside-listview-control)

Comment: tbh I've asked a variation of this question at least 2 or 3 times before, but they were for separate issues (very similarly structured questions though)

& thank You to @蕭為元 , the link you posted helped me to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your itemwDataBound event, look for the value you need then set the button color there. Also you can set the value in the buttons command argument then grab it in the click event.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Access your `Button` on `ItemDataBound` event of the `ListView` to change the color of the `Button` conditionally.

Here is the link which can help you with this:

[datalist itemdatabound event having issues changing item bg color on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852629/datalist-itemdatabound-event-having-issues-changing-item-bg-color-on-condition)